# Azure set subscription command fails via shell script, but works without shell script

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

i'm just trying to execute set of AZ commands via shell scripts.

```
az account set --subscription "test-subscription"
```

If i run the command directly on powershell after `az login` , it works fine.

but if i run the same command via shell scripts, throws subscription doesn't exist in AzureCloud.

**Update:**

The output of az account show command

```
{
  "environmentName": "AzureCloud",
  "homeTenantId": "xxx-xx-xx-x",
  "id": "xx-xx-xx-x-xx",
  "isDefault": true,
  "managedByTenants": [
    {
      "tenantId": "xx-xx-xxx-xx-xx"
    }
  ],
  "name": "subscription-name",
  "state": "Enabled",
  "tenantId": "xx-xx-xx-xxx",
  "user": {
    "name": "fn.ln@xx.com",
    "type": "user"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post what is the output of  az account list

Comment: which shell script? bash?

Comment: @AmitBaranes, yes its a bash script

Comment: @Sajeetharan what are you specifically looking for az account list?

Comment: Does any other az command works from bash?

Comment: Any update this issue?

Comment: @JoyWang, not really, still its not working via shell script.. but i can successfully create Azure eventhubs using az deployment group create command..

Answer (score 3):

Try to specify the `--tenant` with the tenant id of the subscription when you login.

```
az login --tenant '<tenant-id>'
```

Then use

```
az account set --subscription '<subscription-id>'
```

Comment: I have tried to login with tenant id , then try to execute the shell script, same issue..

Comment: Also i'm usng windows, so using Powershell to execute the scripts and commands

Comment: @Shankar What's the output if you run `az account show`? Or try to reinstall the Azure CLI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: updated the question with output of az account show

Comment: @Shankar Is the `subscription-name` which you want? If not, could you find the subscription you want in the output of `az account list`?

Comment: i just changed the subscription name to dummy name to post it here, az account list shows all the subscription i have access to

Comment: @Shankar I know that, I just want to know if the subscription you want to use in `az account set --subscription '<subscription-id>'` existing in the `az account list`?

Comment: yes, the subscription is there.. because i'm able to create resources under that subscription by directly running the commands.. not sure is it something to do with shell script(bash) or i need some windows subsystem for linux

Comment: @Shankar It's so weird, could you make sure you use the correct `<subscription-id>`? Not the name.

Comment: i was using subscription name, if that's the use why running the command directly worked, anyway i will try use the subscrition id

Comment: @Shankar Yes, please try the `subscription-id` instead of the subscription name, it should work.

Comment: Thanks for following up on this.. i tried using subscription-id as well, but still the same issue.

Comment: @Shankar Really weird, please run `az account clear` first then login and try again.